# dataframe calculation - basic minus calculation

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as per below:

```
student  Marks_1   Marks_2
    A1      25      28
    B1      22      24
    C1      18      25
```

Column A - student, 
Column B - Marks_1, 
Column C - Marks_2, 
i want to perform a basic calculation to get the score as per the below formula.

```
A1_Score =(C2-B2)^2
```

Getting Error message:

> "-" not meaningful for factors

expected output:

```
A1_score    9
B1_score    4
C1_score   49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to add your desired additional column:

```
df$score=(df$Marks_1-df$Marks_2)^2
> df
  student Marks_1 Marks_2 score
1      A1      25      28        9
2      B1      22      24        4
3      C1      18      25       49
```

Input dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(student=c("A1","B1","C1"),
               Marks_1=c(25,22,18),
               Marks_2=c(28,24,25))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Your dataset:

```
df=read.table(text="student  Marks_1   Marks_2
A1      25      28
          B1      22      24
          C1      18      25",header=T)
# Create new column based on your formula
df$score=(df$Marks_2-df$Marks_1)^2
```

Output:

```
    student Marks_1 Marks_2 score
1      A1      25      28     9
2      B1      22      24     4
3      C1      18      25    49
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
  header = TRUE, text = 'student  Marks_1   Marks_2
A1      25      28
B1      22      24
C1      18      25')


library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,score:= (Marks_2-Marks_1)^2]
df

   student Marks_1 Marks_2 score
1:      A1      25      28     9
2:      B1      22      24     4
3:      C1      18      25    49
```